# How can I setState and push to an array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

this is my state:

```
class table extends Component {
  state = {
    arr: [],
    numofSub: 1
  };
```

I wish to push an object to the arr with set state through fetch from my database,
the fetch works great I console logged it, I just cant seem to push the object inside the array:

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/api/items')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(inputs => this.setState({ arr: [...inputs] }));

  }
```

Comment: `this.setState({ arr: [...this.state.arr, ...inputs] })`

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried that and I get an empty array when I console log the state, like so: []
​
length: 0
​
<prototype>: Array []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When next state is depended on previous state, is advised to use the functional `setstate` version:

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/api/items')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(inputs => this.setState(state => ({ arr: [state.arr,...inputs] })));
  }
```

As for logging the changes right after `setstate` you should do that inside the [`setState`'s callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). because [`setState` is asynchronous](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710) and may not be updated when you log the `state`:

```
this.setState(state => ({key:value}), () => {
  // this is the callback, its safe to log the updated state
  console.log(this.state);
});
```

Comment: wonderful it works, I completely forgot it was asynchronous, thank you!

Comment: @AlexAlex Glad i could help